# Math based proof for currency changes

Tags: currency, nonexpert, exchange-rates

This isn't part of my homework but I am genuinely interested in the mathematical proof behind this question (this is my line of work currently). I tried to work through it but after 2 hours gave up. It is beyond the scope of my intermediate economics class but I wanted to see what a proof would look like for it.

Suppose that the Japanese yen rises against the U.S. dollar—that is, it will take more dollars to
buy a given amount of Japanese yen. Explain why this increase simultaneously increases the
real price of Japanese cars for U.S. consumers and lowers the real price of U.S. automobiles for
Japanese consumers.

Comment: Welcome! Could you tell us about the work you did during those two hours? Although it's not a homework question, it's a related homework question... see https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions

Comment: If you want a mathematical proof, you need a mathematical model first.

Answer (score 1):

So a US consumer picks their non-car bundle of goods, $x$, with prices $p$ denominated in dollars. The price of an American car is $a$ dollars, the price of a Japanese car is $y$ yen, and the price of a dollar in yen is the exchange rate, $r$ (how many yen does a dollar buy?). If the consumer buys an American car, $z = 1$, yielding utility $u_a$ at a price of $a$, and if the consumer buys a Japanese car, $z=0$, yielding utility $u_j$ at a price of $j$, $z \in [0,1]$.

Then the consumer is solving
$$
\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}_N,z\in [0,1]} u(x) + u_a z + u_j (1-z)
$$
subject to $p'x + z a + (1-z) r j \le I$ where $I$ is the consumer's wealth.

The Lagrangian is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{L} &=& u(x) + u_a z + u_j (1-z) - \lambda (p'x + za + (1-z)rj - I) \\
&=& [u(x)-\lambda (p'x-I)] + z(u_a-\lambda a - u_j + \lambda rj) -\lambda rj + +u_j
\end{eqnarray*}
The part in $[...]$ is the standard consumer problem: pick a basket of goods $x$ with income $I$ and prices $p$. The $z$ must be in $[0,1]$, with 1 meaning "buy American" and 0 meaning "buy Japanese". So if $u_a - \lambda a > u_j - \lambda rj$, the consumer buys American, and otherwise Japanese.

Now, if we increase $r$, what happens to the consumer's maximized utility?  The envelope theorem tells us that if we want to see how welfare varies with a parameter, we partially differentiate with respect to that, then evaluate the Lagrangian at the optimum. Let's do that:
$$
\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial r} = (1-z) \lambda j
$$
So if the consumer is buying American, $z^*=1$, and this equals zero: the dollar becoming strong doesn't affect his welfare, because he is buying the American car anyway.  But if $z^*=0$, he is buying Japanese, and a stronger dollar makes it easier to pay the $j$ price denominated in yen.

If you think about the Japanese consumer, everything is the same, except $r$ is going down and not up: he is worse off if he is buying an American car, but the same if buying a Japanese car.

Now, how is $r$ determined in equilibrium?  The above problem gives you a demand curve for yen by American consumers: the ones who want to buy Japanese cars, i.e., they have a high $u_j$ relative to $u_a$.  A similar problem gives demand for American cars by Japanese consumers, i.e. those Japanese households for whom $u_a$ is large relative to $u_j$. As the price $r$ varies, people will opt in or out of the market for the cars made by the other country. Equilibrium in the currency market occurs where the flow of dollars from Americans to Japanese and the flow of yen from Japanese to Americans is equal, just like your regular Supply-And-Demand diagram. This means that if a dollar buys fewer yen in equilibrium, it must also mean that yen buy more dollars in equilibrium, and vice versa.

Comment: This answer seems like overkill for a question that can essentially be answered by the formula $p_{JPY} \cdot E_{USD/JPY}$.

Comment: And $[0,1]$ should be replaced by $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: $[0,1]$ is just the probability of purchase, there is no reason to make it discrete. The way it is written allows people to be indifferent between goods, so any $z\in[0,1]$ is acceptable. This keeps demand curves convex valued, which can matter for existence of equilibrium.

Comment: @Giskard An accounting identity is not an explanation. It provides no information about how the quantities might respond to changes in consumer tastes or firm technology. The model I sketched outlines how to get household currency demand as a function of what products consumers which to purchase from other countries, and the accounting identity you suggest becomes a market-clearing condition.  That's the difference between economics and accounting.

Comment: Well, but then you are dealing with a model in which it is possible that an optimizing consumer throws a coin to decide which car to buy and pays $\frac{a+j}{2}$...

Comment: @VARulle pays $\frac{a+rj}{2}$ *in expectation*, or any convex combination of $a$ and $rj$ in expectation.  That is fine.  But ex post, the consumer will pay $a$ or $rj$.  If you like, you can imagine a large number of customers, all of whom buy American or Japanese with probability 1, but the population proportions are $1/2$, or whatever you want.

Comment: No, that's not fine. Your *realized* expenditure is constrained by your income, not your expected one. And unless there is a competitive market for lottery tickets with cars as prizes, you can't buy a 10% chance of a \$20k car with an income of \$2k. Even a population of consumers with a budget of \$2k each cannot split into 90% who don't buy a car and 10% who do.

Comment: @VARulle Suppose any $z\in[0,1]$ is part of the solution correspondence. Then there is $x_0$ that corresponds to $z=0$ which maximizes the household's utility and satisfies the budget constraint when that household buys American, and an $x_1$ that corresponds to $z=1$ which maximizes the household's utility and satisfies the budget constraint when the household buys Japanese.  Have $z$ proportion of people buy American and $x_0$, and $(1-z)$ proportion buy Japanese and $x_1$.  This is how you "purify" mixed strategies to interpret them as population proportions instead of literal randomization

Comment: That's not true. You ignore the possibility of corner solutions, e.g. if $a>I$, which makes your $x_1$ negative. Just try to solve your constrained optimization problem with a single non-car good and the values $p=5$, $r=1$, $a=20$, $j=10$, $I=15$, $u(x)=\sqrt{x}$. You'll find the optimal bundle at $x^*=0$, $z^*=\frac12$ with your $x_0=1$ and $x_1=-1$, which makes no sense.

Comment: Forgot to add the parameters $u_a=8$, $u_j=5$.

Comment: @Renard Apart from some economical disputable issues that the optimization problem mixes up a direct utility function with an indirect utility function, the optimization problem is treated as a problem with equality constraints though it must obviously be treated as a one with inequalities, this includes also the budget constraint. The decision variable $x$ must be bounded from below, and the decision variable $z$ must be drawn from the interval $[0,1]$, which implies that we have to consider inequality constraints given by $-x \le 0, -z \le 0$ and $z - 1 \le 0$. (to be continued)

Comment: However, these constraints must be captured by the optimization problem. In contrast, we have to observe by the second equation that $z$ is treated as parameter, which is obviously wrong. From a mathematical point of view, one has to rely on the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions to get the correct results.